# Android Buttons as part of a larger png graphic

Tags: android, layout, button

I 've a big png which has some buttons "drawn" on it as images. Can I use it in a way that it can be shared as both background and buttons?

For example, I can load it as a background which will have "buttons" in , say, position X 5 Y 5 to position X 100 Y 100, and "button" in position X 110 Y 110 to X 200 Y 200.

If this is possible, can I also have "two state" buttons? Different image for "pressed" etc.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've said, it sounds like a good solution might be separating the buttons from the rest of the png.  Set the button-less image as the background of your parent layout, then add your buttons on top of it.  If the buttons cannot be decoupled from the rest of the background, you'll probably need to use completely transparent buttons.

Something to keep in mind would be that, because screen sizes differ, what your intend to do probably best achieved by adding the buttons programatically and setting their size and position relative to the current screen size.  Also good to remember is that, due to this fragmentation, setting an image with the `android:background` attribute could possibly resize and distort your image, changing the target location for your buttons.

As for multi-state buttons, here's the part of the dev guide that can help you: (What you'll need is the `android:state_pressed` attribute)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

If you need further help, it might be easier if you give it a try yourself and see what issues arise, so that you can focus your question, post some code, and get a more detailed response.  What you're asking is pretty broad.  Good luck!

Comment: Thx for your comment, I 've already decided to use separated buttons. Too many problems when using a "shared" image.